# 'Next' action button won't click through images stored on local folder

Tags: r, shiny, shinyapps, action-button

I am new to shiny and trying to make an app which allows users to view images one by one. I have thousands of JPGs in a folder and I want to be able to display an image and allow a user to click a button and the next image in that folder will be displayed (And the old one deleted)
So far I can load up the first image, but when I click next I get an error message "invalid filename argument".

Is anyone able to advise where I'm going wrong please?

My code is as follows:

```
dir <- "local.dir/www"
img_files <- list.files(dir, full.names = TRUE)

ui <- pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel("Data"),
  sidebarPanel(actionButton("goButton", "Next")),
    plotOutput("plot", height=500)
)
server <- function(input, output,session) {
  
    values <- reactiveValues()
  values$count <- 1
  
   plot <- eventReactive(input$goButton,{
    
    
    if(values$count != length(img_files)){
      values$count <- values$count + 1
      return(img_files[values$count])
    }
    else{
         return(img_files[length(img_files)])
    }
  })
  
  output$plot <- renderImage({
        if(input$goButton == 0){
      return(list(src = img_files[1]))
    }
    img()
  }, deleteFile = TRUE)  
  
}


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: `list.files` returns a `list`.  So you need to reference its individual elements with `[[]]`, not `[]`.  Does that help?

Comment: at a glance I noticed that you create an object called `plot` and its not used anywhere, also later you seem to use something called img `img()` which has not been defined; perhaps at a minimum these are intended to be related but have not been matched

Comment: Change `img()` to `plot()` in `output$plot` as plot is your eventReactive object name.

Comment: thanks for your comments. I have tried all of the above but still get the same error message